# css-grid - collapse empty columns and align siblings content

Tags: css, css-grid

can't find out answer of how to collapse empty columns and align sibling content around this empty block, by using css-grid.

In the example, I manually and as an example showed how the green block should level out when it is alone.
In other words, if some block is missing, then everything else should be centered. How do I do it better?

https://jsfiddle.net/qsLgxtcp/3/

[JSFiddle preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKCw1.png)

**HTML**

```
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid__child grid__child--aside">Aside</div>
  <div class="grid__child grid__child--controllers">
    <div class="grid__child-label">
      Just some absolute label for example
    </div>
    Controller
  </div>
</div>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid__child grid__child--controllers">
    <div class="grid__child-label">
      Just some absolute label for example
    </div>
    Single Controller
  </div>
</div>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid__child grid__child--single grid__child--controllers">
    <div class="grid__child-label">
      Just some absolute label for example
    </div>
    Expected align, when it's single
  </div>
</div>
```

**SCSS**

```
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 16px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(9, 1fr);
  grid-template-areas: 'aside aside aside . controllers controllers controllers controllers controllers';
  margin: 16px auto;
  width: 300px;
  &__child {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 4px 8px;
    color: black;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    &--aside {
      grid-area: aside;
      background-color: lightblue;
    }
    &--controllers {
      position: relative;
      grid-area: controllers;
      background-color: gold;
    }
    &--single {
      background-color: springgreen;
      transform: translateX(-50%);
    }
    &-label {
      position: absolute;
      right: 100%;
      top: 50%;
      width: 16px;
      height: 16px;
      transform: translate(-16px, -50%);
      background-color: gray;
      font-size: 0;
      line-height: 0;
      letter-spacing: -1px;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is not possible with CSS-Grid...if it was it wouldn't be a grid.

Comment: How about **auto-fit** css property. Is it suitable?

Comment: No...once you have something in the first column (the Aside) it sets the width for that column whether there is anything in it or not. What it seems you really want are **rows** not a grid.

Comment: I think it should be some way to collapse empty columns and it's relative gap while using **grid-template-areas**, because sometimes we don't really know is it template areas will be empty or not...